# Similar font to Montserrat Alternates?

Tags: fonts, sans-serif, black

I'm looking for a **black, sans-serif font that has curved (curly?) "W" and/or "A" uppercase**, instead of the typical "spiky" "W" or "A" of sans-serif.
It can be free and also paying license.

Like this example of Montserrat Alternates or even more "curvy":
[image: Example]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't really looked at all, have you?

I reduced your image to just the W and A and ran it through [WhatTheFont.com](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/result)

[image]

These are merely a *few* suggestions, there are more.

- [Eastman](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/zetafonts/eastman/alternate-extrabold/)
- [Sinn Bold](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/haiku/sinn/bold/)
- [Quinoa Rounded Black](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/catharsis-fonts/quinoa/round-black/)
- [Slug Single](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/facetype/slug/single/)
- [Publica Play Extra Bold](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/facetype/publica-play/extra-bold/)
- [Madurai Normal Black](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/insigne/madurai/black/)
- [Remora Sans W5-Black](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/g-type/remora-sans/w5-black/)

Comment: Also anything in the Bauhaus family (and its spinoffs).

Comment: "You haven't really looked at all, have you? "
No, I didn't 

Answer (score 1):

This has similarities to Art Deco lettering. Try [Refrigerator Deluxe](https://www.marksimonson.com/assets/content/fonts/RefrigeratorDeluxeSpecimen.pdf) which has a lot of weights, or [LTC Tourist Gothic Alternate](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/lanston/ltc-tourist-gothic) for a condensed style.