# Looking for a specific font and am struggling Very Round A's, O's, S's etc

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

UPDATE!!  I used Tailwind as suggested by JBrenan to create this draft.  Thanks JBrenan.  I did have to replace the w from that font group and use Arial Rounded for that but otherwise I think it turned out really well!  Thanks for the help!  Here's a pic of the draft  Obviously in the original, the middle neon bars wrap around the front.  I'm actually going to make this into some stickers and a piece of framed art at some point, but the real plan is to use some HDPE Plastic sheet about 1" think and recreate a miniature sign.  I'll use white and then drill in through the "building side" of the sign and install some lights.  Then after using an adhesion enhancer, I'll paint the black onto it and try to etch the paint off so the white HDPE shows through.  I may have to switch to white painted lexan but we'll see!

[image]

And a 2 sided version with a wraparound front

[image]

Trying to recreate this old family restaurant sign for my parents.  It was originally Neon, so the letters are more rounded.  Any Ideas?

Didn't know there were critique guidelines folks, sorry.  Here's some additional detail based on what I gleaned from there.
I've used Find My Font for several hours, trying multiple letters but particularly focusing on the "A, S, O" when I was searching.  The A is unusual to me and when I find a font that's close with the others, the A is off.  I've also spent several hours on Dafont and other font sizes searching random.  Since I don't do this for a living, I don't exactly know how to search productively on those sites. I've also checked all the stock fonts on my computer.  This sign would have been made around somewhere in the 40's early 50's I'm guessing.

I hope this helps a little more.  I've still searching although Tailwind found by JBrenan seems very close and may warrant the purchase!  Please keep in mind, that I'm not a graphic designer (I'm a social worker) and I'm not doing this for money, just trying to recreate a sign (In miniature) from my mom's childhood for her!

Comment: Please edit your question to follow our [critique guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366).

Comment: Look through these https://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=round&text=SODA+BAR+CAFE

Comment: You sacrifice a lot of other nice letter features just to have the rounded A and O, which I feel could be traced after finding a closer font. I would look for that same thickness, the S, the R... Then add the rounded features.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I found. It is not free but with the name (Tailwind)

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't this be a part of your question, not an answer?

Comment: Man that is close!  Better than what I've fount through hours of searching with the Find my Font App and googling over and over!

Answer (score 0):

See [answers for a question from last year](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/142623/similar-font-to-montserrat-alternates/142634) also about this style of Art Deco lettering, Scott had lots of ideas. Like all signage of the time the original sign won't be a printing font, although it certainly could be a standard lettering available from a manufacturer.